# Set field if row field is not duplicated

Tags: mysql

I want to set the field `coins` to `100`, in the `accounts` table for every row that has a unique  `PASSWORD`.

Is that possible in MySQL?

Comment: Just give me the answer, instead of writing useless comments.

Comment: I did just give you the answer. You asked "is that possible in MySQL". It is. You need to try something yourself before asking to be spoonfed code here.

Comment: I tried, searched alot, maybe I've used wrong search terms, but I didnt find the answer at all...

Comment: The [Alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Comment: ^ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
UPDATE accounts
SET coins = 100
WHERE userid IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT userid
        FROM accounts AS a
        GROUP BY passwd
        HAVING COUNT(passwd) = 1
        ) AS a
    )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE accounts a JOIN
( SELECT PASSWORD, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM accounts 
  GROUP BY PASSWORD
  HAVING cnt < 2 ) singles
ON a.PASSWORD = singles.PASSWORD
SET a.coins = 100
```